# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I started learning jQuery and JavaScript this morning and I've run in to some issues.

I'm trying to make a extremely simple application that can count up and down. I've experimented back and forth and this is my code so far.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function Number(startingNumber) {
        if($.type(startingNumber)=="number"){
            number = startingNumber;
        }else{
            number = 0;
        }

        inc: function(number) { //Error Here!
            this.number = this.number + number;
            updateNumberText();
        }

        dec: function(number) {
            this.number = this.number - number;
            updateNumberText();
        }
    };

    var newN = new Number(50);
    updateNumberText();


    function updateNumberText() {
        $('#number').text(newN.number + "");
        console.log('number updated!');
    }


    $('#decButton').on('click', function() {
        newN.dec(1);
    });

    $('#incButton').on('click', function() {
        newN.inc(1);
    });
});
```

And I've got the following error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token '('**.
I just can't get my head around what's wrong, can't find any syntax errors.

Here are my HTML and CSS files as well.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="randtime.css"/>

    <title>learning</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="number">0</div>
    <button id="incButton">increase</button>
    <button id="decButton">decrease</button>
</body>
```

```
div {
font-size: 400%;
}

#number {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: add }); on the last line :)

Comment: Your code contains lot of syntax error, just open your console and fix everything..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy , he couldn't so he asked here .

Comment: @PratikJoshi Then we should close it under `"why this code not working..?"` :)

Comment: Wow, my mistake. Accidentally missed out on }); when I copied my code, so that's not the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The private methods for *"functional objects"* in JavaScript should be defined in a different way:

```
function Number(startingNumber) {
    // ...

    this.inc = function(number) {
        this.number += number;
        updateNumberText();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried declaring them like this but then I received errors when calling them from outside the object. newN.inc(); for example

Comment: @frsvll This should work fine if you don't have other errors: http://jsfiddle.net/LqAEL/.